# I want to add watermark to Pdf Stream using Itext7

Tags: c#, itext7, html-to-pdf

this is my code that i am using now

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();

var htmmml = @"<h1>some html string </h1>";

// pdfHTML specific code
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmmml, ms, converterProperties);

PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfStream), new PdfWriter(pdfStream));
// Document to add layout elements: paragraphs, images etc
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

// Load image from disk
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(@"D:\TestWebApp\TestWebApp\imgs\WATERMARK.jpeg");
// Create layout image object and provide parameters. Page number = 1
Image image = new Image(imageData).ScaleAbsolute(100, 200).SetFixedPosition(1, 25, 25);
// This adds the image to the page
document.Add(image);
```

thing is after converting html to ms , ms is being disposed and i cant access it anymore. i want to convert html to pdf with watermark .

Answer (score 1):

It probably would be more convenient for you to use HtmlConverter's *convertToDocument* or *convertToElements* methods.

The former one returns a *Document* instance which you can then process (for example, add a watermark).

The latter one returns the list of html elements which construct the html file. Then you can create a *Document* and add these elements to this document.

Comment: *"The former one returns a *Document* instance which you can then process"* - Is that document constructed with `immediateFlush` set to `false`? Otherwise it might be difficult to add watermarks to the returned document. (I don't know, I essentially don't do any HTML to PDF stuff...)

Comment: Ah, I found it, one has to set the `immediateFlush` value in `ConverterProperties` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

When a `MemoryStream` is closed, you can still retrieve its contents using the `ToArray` method, see the note in the documentation:

> #### MemoryStream.ToArray Method
>
> ...
>
> This method returns a copy of the contents of the MemoryStream as a byte array. If the current instance was constructed on a provided byte array, a copy of the section of the array to which this instance has access is returned. See the MemoryStream constructor for details.
>
> > Note
> >
> > This method works when the MemoryStream is closed.

Thus, you should be allowed to switch the order of your lines

```
MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmmml, ms, converterProperties);
```

to

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmmml, ms, converterProperties);
MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
```

to have `pdfStream` contain the `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf` for further processing.